# LookupAccountName returns the local PC Domain instead of the logged in AD Domain

Tags: winapi

I've been using

```
LookupAccountName
```

using the returned value from

```
GetUserName
```

to retrieve the current logged on AD Domain Name.

This has been happily working for a while on a number of machines with a number of different NT based OS's

That is, until today, when instead of returning the logged in AD Domain, it returned the Computer Name as the domain.

Can anyone explain why this would happen less than 0.5% of the time?

Comment: And you're 100% sure that the user is logged in to a domain account on a machine that's a domain member?

Comment: @Deanna yes. had full access to all shares, logged in to exchange correctly, no login popups. only returned the pc domain :(

Comment: None of that guarantees they are logged in to a domain account.

Comment: @Deanna They log into the domain at the logon/welcome screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an account on the local computer with the same name as the Active Directory username then `LookupAccountName` will return the local computer name (being the local Domain Name), rather than the required AD Domain name.

Instead I should use `GetUserNameEx` with `NameUserPrincipal` to return the current user's principal name, which can be fed into `LookupAccountName` to return the logged in Domain.